# Hide browser scrollbar but keep contents at its original place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sample html, query, css layout [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDTnY/). What it does right now it when I click on Hidden link then it hides browser scrollbar(Which is fine and I want this effect). But when scrollbar disappears then the contents or text in p tags stretches to the right which I do not want. How can I hide scrollbar and also keep all contents in it original place?

Please see my code over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDTnY/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width to the window width instead of 100%:

```
$("p").css("width", $(window).width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zDTnY/5/